# Stop Android Studio from automatically showing design / preview when editing xml

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio is showing me design / preview windows when choosing to edit an xml layout which sometimes takes a long time to load on my PC. Is it possible to configure the environment so that it stops doing so? When I choose to edit an xml I expect it to just open the file and do nothing else.

Edit:
I can close the window as you are suggesting. What I can't do is stop it from popping out automatically after I opened it previously and automatic switching to design tab.

Comment: you can remove preview by click on preview where will be multiple option just click on remove from side bar and when you want again preview then go view->tool window->preview it will show you preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found the answer in Android Studio right after looking at this... You can change it in settings/preferences:

[image: settings]

Answer (score 1):

You can **minimize** design windows as below.

[image: hiding android studio design view]

This action will minimize design view until you click on **Preview** button again ,reinstalling your android studio

or as rachna said you can restore design windows again by flowing this **View>Tool Windows>Preview**

Comment: I can hide the preview, but when I show it again it automatically pops up next time. I guess its a feature...

Comment: what do you mean by "show it again" . You  mean you have reopened the xml layout or reclick on preview. would you explain it ?

Comment: Yes, I do In certain occasions want to see the design in preview but I never want it to open automatically.

Comment: @JanMálek if you are satisfied with answer you can vote up please